# Splitting numpy arrays based on categorical variable

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to split up the ages and weights based on the categorical variable "obese" and then plot the two sets with different colors. I think I might be doing the list comprehension wrong. When I plot I only see one color and all data points.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ages = np.array([20, 22, 23, 25, 27])
weights = np.array([140, 144, 150, 156, 160])
obese = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

ages_normal = [ages for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 0]
weights_normal = [weights for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 0]

ages_obese = [ages for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 1]
weights_obese = [weights for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 1]

plt.scatter(ages_normal, weights_normal, color = "b")
plt.scatter(ages_obese, weights_obese, color = "r")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ages = np.array([20, 22, 23, 25, 27])
weights = np.array([140, 144, 150, 156, 160])
obese = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

data = zip(ages, weights, obese)

data_normal = np.array([(a,w) for (a,w,o) in data if o == 0])
data_obese  = np.array([(a,w) for (a,w,o) in data if o == 1])

plt.scatter(data_normal[:,0], data_normal[:,1], color = "b")
plt.scatter(data_obese[:,0],  data_obese[:,1], color = "r")

plt.show()
```

But this might be more efficient:

```
data = np.array(np.vstack([ages, weights, obese])).T

ind_n = np.where(data[:,2] == 0)
ind_o = np.where(data[:,2] == 1)

plt.scatter(data[ind_n,0], data[ind_n,1], color = "b")
plt.scatter(data[ind_o,0], data[ind_o,1], color = "r")
```

But you are correct, the list comprehensions are a bit off, maybe you wanted something like:

```
ages_normal = [ages[i] for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 0]
weights_normal = [weights[i] for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 0]

ages_obese = [ages[i] for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 1]
weights_obese = [weights[i] for i in range(0, len(obese)) if obese[i] == 1]
```

The difference is the added indexing on `ages`/`weights`.

All three approachs generates the graph you're looking for.

Comment: @user2469211 no problem, I added in a third method that uses `np.where` that seems more efficient -- it doesn't duplicate the normal/obese data in additional arrays.

Comment: Is np.array with the zip function faster because the computations now happen on an np.array?

Comment: No, that didn't seem very efficient (I've since changed it) -- the efficiency was from not effectively duplicating `data` when I created `data_normal` and `data_obsese` -- instead, in the second method, I just create a list of matching indices `ind_n`/`ind_o`, and keep only one copy of `data` around.